# How can I give a Variable from one class to another and return the changed variable back?

Tags: flutter, dart, return

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to get the countdown-variable from the SetTimerPage to the CupertinoTimePickerButton-Page. Then change it there to the chosen time and give it back. Next I want to give the changed countdown to the next page where a countdown animation starts. I'm also open for suggestions to improve my syntax. Thank you :)

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: SetTimerPage(),
    );
  }
}

class SetTimerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SetTimerPageState createState() => _SetTimerPageState();
}

class _SetTimerPageState extends State<SetTimerPage> {
  final Duration countdown = Duration(minutes: 0, seconds: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('RoundONE'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            CustomRowWidget(
              icon: Icons.alarm_sharp,
              text: 'COUNTDOWN',
              button: CupertinoTimePickerButton(passedValue: countdown),
            ),
            StartButton(countdown: countdown),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CupertinoTimePickerButton extends StatefulWidget {
  Duration passedValue;

  CupertinoTimePickerButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.passedValue,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CupertinoTimePickerButtonState createState() =>
      _CupertinoTimePickerButtonState();
}

class _CupertinoTimePickerButtonState extends State<CupertinoTimePickerButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      child: Text(
        _formatDuration(widget.passedValue),
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      onPressed: () {
        _cupertinoTimeSetter(context);
      },
    );
  }

  Future _cupertinoTimeSetter(BuildContext context) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext builder) {
        return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height / 2,
          child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
            onTimerDurationChanged: (Duration newDuration) {
              setState(() {
                widget.passedValue = newDuration;
              });
            },
            minuteInterval: 1,
            secondInterval: 5,
            mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.ms,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  String _formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return "$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use a call back that will give back the value to it's parent and for this case you can use ValueChanged. Then after the parent will be incharged to change the variable value.

```
class SetTimerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SetTimerPageState createState() => _SetTimerPageState();
}

class _SetTimerPageState extends State<SetTimerPage> {
  Duration countdown;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    countdown = Duration(minutes: 0, seconds: 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('RoundONE'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            CustomRowWidget(
              icon: Icons.alarm_sharp,
              text: 'COUNTDOWN',
              button: CupertinoTimePickerButton(
                passedValue: countdown,
                onChanged: (Duration duration) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.countdown = duration;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            StartButton(countdown: countdown),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CupertinoTimePickerButton extends StatelessWidget {

  final Duration passedValue;
  final ValueChanged<Duration> onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      child: Text(
        _formatDuration(widget.passedValue),
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      onPressed: () {
        _cupertinoTimeSetter(context);
      },
    );
  }

  Future _cupertinoTimeSetter(BuildContext context) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext builder) {
        return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height / 2,
          child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
            onTimerDurationChanged: this.onChanged,
            minuteInterval: 1,
            secondInterval: 5,
            mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.ms,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  String _formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return "$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
  }
}
```